# MySQL joins returns more then expected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

i want some records from more then three MySQL Tables with joins but i am getting unexpected records what is wrong with this query..

1)

### admit_card TABLE

```
class_id|exam_id|subject_id|  exam_date  |exam_time_from|exam_time_to
   1       1         S1      02/12/2016    11:00            02:00    
   2       1         S1      01/12/2016    11:00            02:00    
   2       1         S4      02/12/2016    11:00            02:00
```

### subjects TABLE

```
section_id_fk|subject_code|subject_name
   1             S1          HINDI
   2             S1          HINDI
   2             S4          COMPUTER
```

### class_details TABLE

```
class_id_pk|class_name
   1           FIRST
   2           SECOND
```

### section_details TABLE

```
section_id_pk|class_id_fk|section_name|
   1               1          A
   2               2          A
```

now I want to fetch record from admit_card table which has three records but here joins are mandatory because in admit card,I have class_id exam_id and subject_id column which can get through their superior table. now my query is like :

```
SELECT class_name,section_name,subject_code,subject_name,ac.exam_date, ac.exam_time_from,ac.exam_time_to 
FROM admit_card ac 
LEFT OUTER JOIN section_details sd ON sd.section_id_pk = ac.class_id 
JOIN class_details cd ON cd.class_id_pk = sd.class_id_fk 
JOIN subjects ON sd.section_id_pk = subjects.section_id_fk 
JOIN admit_card ON admit_card.subject_id = subjects.subject_code;
```

### EXPECTED ANSWER

```
1) FIRST  |A|    S1|  HINDI   |02/12/2016 |  11:00| 02:00
2) SECOND |A|    S1|  HINDI   |01/12/2016 |  11:00| 02:00
3) SECOND |A|    S4|  COMP    |02/12/2016 |  11:00| 12:00
```

Comment: Why are you joining `section_id_pk` with `class_id`? Shouldn't it be `ON sd.class_id_fk = ac.class_id`?

Comment: I want to fetch the record from section_details and class_details tables. class_id is primary key which is referred foreign key in section table..

Comment: But the foreign key is `class_id_fk`, but you're using `section_id_pk`.

Comment: don't confuse with the column name. inside the admit_card table, the class_id is same as section_details table section_id_pk

Comment: What are the results you're trying to get, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: Why do you have `class_id_fk` in `section_details` if it's the same as `section_id_pk`?

Comment: I want only three rows as a result but I am getting 8 rows. which has duplicate or inappropriate values

Comment: 1)  FIRST      |A  |  S1|  HINDI   |02/12/2016 |  11:00|  02:00
2 ) SECOND |A|    S1|  HINDI    |02/12/2016 |  11:00|  02:00
3)  SECOND |A|    S4|  COMP|  02/12/2016 |    11:00| 12:00

Comment: Comments don't allow formatting. Put it in the question.

Comment: I updated the expected result in the question, please look into this

Comment: Why shouldn't you get any of the exams on 01/12/2016?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake the second result will contain 01/12/2016. now you may proceed.

Comment: Why are you joining again with `admit_card` on the last line?

Comment: admit_card table have subject_id so how do I cross check from subject table that's y I am joining the both table, may i get your email or any thing so that i can send you schema or db ..

Comment: I am trouble with this query for 5 days, not getting the answer and I am not that much good with MySQL.. if you could then, please

Comment: I posted an answer below, don't you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have `admit_card` in the query twice. To join the columns with different tables, specify them both in the same `ON` clause.

```
SELECT class_name,section_name,subject_code,subject_name,ac.exam_date, ac.exam_time_from,ac.exam_time_to 
FROM admit_card ac 
LEFT OUTER JOIN section_details sd ON sd.section_id_pk = ac.class_id 
JOIN class_details cd ON cd.class_id_pk = sd.class_id_fk 
JOIN subjects ON sd.section_id_pk = subjects.section_id_fk AND ac.subject_id = subjects.subject_code
```

Result:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
| class_name | section_name | subject_code | subject_name | exam_date           | exam_time_from | exam_time_to |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
| FIRST      | A            | S1           | HINDI        | 2016-02-12 00:00:00 | 11:00          | 02:00        |
| SECOND     | A            | S1           | HINDI        | 2016-01-12 00:00:00 | 11:00          | 02:00        |
| SECOND     | A            | S4           | COMPUTER     | 2016-02-12 00:00:00 | 11:00          | 02:00        |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
```